# Dishes were used without tevilat keilim; can one just do tevila now or is something else needed?

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization, tevilas-keilim-dipping

If dishes have only ever been used for kosher food but they were not *toveled* (immersed), what steps must be taken per *halacha* to be able to continue using them?  Can one just take them to the *mikvah* now, or do you have to treat them as if they had been used for non-kosher food and start over (if possible) with boiling, heat, etc to *kasher* them first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only *kelim* (vessels) which absorbed *issur* (forbidden substances) need to be kashered. A *kli* which may have *issur* stuck to the surface, but not absorbed should be scrubbed. *Keilim* which were only used with kosher are clear to be *toiveled*. See [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 121](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4395).

Another point concerning old *keilim* is to make sure there is nothing on the surface which would be a separation between the *kli* and the water, see the previous siman [YD 120](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4389), siff 13 concerning rust on a *kli*.